# How with Maximo Java customization to make an attribute required?

Tags: java, customization, maximo

I have tried the following code and it doesn't seem to work:

```
this.setFieldFlag("VIEW.LOC". MboConstants.REQUIRED, True)
```

Comment: Please follow the [contribution guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. What do you expect as a result? Is there an error message? Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: Which class did you extend? Which method? Did you associate it with an object or attribute? Are you aware that `VIEW.LOC` will be seen as a relationship-dot-attributename, so the `LOC` attribute at the end of the `VIEW` relationship is what will be made required?

Comment: I am not extending a class.  I am just trying to set a field in Maximo to required in the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : getMboValue("VIEW.LOC").setRequired(true);